# Problems with installation - crashes

Tags: dual-boot, system-installation

I just installed 64 bit Ubuntu on an old HP desktop with an SSD.  I am dual booting with Windows 8.

Ubuntu loads correctly about 50% of the time, otherwise I have to hard reset.  The rest of the time, when I open an application, the OS freezes entirely and I have to hard reset.  I can't actually use the machine.

Does anyone know how to proceed?  Can I erase the Ubuntu partition(s) and start over?  I prefer not to have to set up Windows again, so I prefer to avoid a full hard disk format.

Comment: Be careful; you should be aware that if you simply erase the Ubuntu partition, you will also be erasing the bootloader menu, and will not be able to access windows without replacing the original windows bootloader. As far as reinstalling, that's probably OK, but may not fix your problem.

Answer (score 0):

This might be related to the solid state drive locking up, try this: edit grub configuration file /etc/default/grub

```
sudo nano /etc/default/grub
```

to change the GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX line to:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="libata.force=noncq"
```

Then save and update grub

```
sudo update-grub
```

Comment: Did you try this?  Did it fix your problem?